# How to stop never-ending stream of blk_update_request errors?

Tags: linux, rhel, console, vmware, floppy

Have a RHEL 7 virtual server that people are currently working in, but the console in vSphere is just showing a "blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0" every few minutes or so, is there a way to exit this loop and get back to a normal console/command line **without rebooting the server** (like I said people are currently working in that environment)?

I'm not even worried about the error, from what I understand it's because the machine thinks there's a floppy drive attached, probably because of the backup software touching that server and testing some backup volume mounts and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unload the `floppy` device driver and blacklist it:

```
modprobe -r floppy
echo "blacklist floppy" >/etc/modprobe.d/no-floppy.conf
depmod
```

If something keeps polling `/dev/fd0`, you may have to try the first command a few times, or perhaps use `fuser -c /dev/fd0` to determine the process accessing the floppy device, and temporarily stop it while you remove the `floppy` module and blacklist it so that it won't be autoloaded again.

And the console login prompt is still there, although it may be swamped by the error messages.

By the way, the root cause of the error messages is that either VMware's floppy emulation is less than perfect, or someone has deleted the floppy drive from the virtual machine configuration. And then you have something like `udisksd` running that keeps polling the "floppy drive" every now and then.

Comment: There is no reason to run `depmod` here.